# Using android sdk classes in ndk

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am pretty new to using android ndk. Is it possible to use android/ standard java classes in native c code using JNI getClass method ? If it is possible, can someone point me to reference code ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The Android NDK comes with some simple examples.  The relevant JNI function is FindClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use NDK, I suggest that learning the JNI programming with JavaSE. There is an official page for [JNI tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html).